# How to fix error - end of central directory record signature not found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

First, I split the video into frames with ffmpeg (on the Converter server, Windows), after that I create an archive that I need to transfer to another server (Generator server, Linux), where the archive with video and/or image, frames, and the data.json file should be unzipped, and the contents of the archive should be used further.

For unzipping, I took the extract-zip library (based on yauzl) and used promisify from the util module.

The problem is that when I send an image to the Converter for processing, everything works as it should; however, when I send a video, I get this error - 'end of central directory record signature not found'.

It seems to me that the problem is related to asynchrony or the event-loop.

- I tried not to use promisify, but then I have the following problem - at the moment when I need to use data from the archive, this archive does not yet exist ('folder do not exist');
- Tried some more libraries for unarchiving adamzip, unzip, decompress, node-zip;
- I tried to make a chain of promises;

```
...
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')
cosnt util = require('util')
const extractZip = util.promisify(require('extract-zip'))
...

...
/**
* Factory that creates a project based on the archive.
* @param {string} archive Path to the source archive
* @returns {Promise.<Project>}
*/
static async create (archive) {
  const dir = fs.mkdtempSync(path.join(this.baseDir, '/'))
  await extractZip(archive, { dir })
  const data = await fs.readJson(path.join(dir, 'data.json'))
  return new this(data, dir)
}
...

/* Tried to do this w/ chaining promises:

static async create (archive) {
  const dir = fs.mkdtempSync(path.join(this.baseDir, '/'))
  await extractZip(archive, { dir })
   .then( async () => {
    const data = await fs.readJson(path.join(dir, 'data.json'))
    return data
   })
   .then( async (data) => {
    return new this(data, dir)
   })
}

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turned out that I had been downloading a large archive from the server asynchronously, so correcting this moment, everything worked as it should.

```
Wrong:
fs.writeFile(...)
Correct:
fs.writeFileSync(...)
```

Conclusion: faced with a similar problem - you should go through the entire chain of data transfer and functions/call stack that is involved in it.